# SQL - Join custom property table's data to main table in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract data from two tables. The data in the first table (**projects**) is customized by the user properties from the second one (**custom_values**). The list and type of custom properties is described in the third table (**custom_fields**):

[image]

I need to write a query or procedure that extracts data from the first table (**projects**), adding to it all custom values related to the record from the table **custom_values**, like this:

[image]

I can’t change the database structure. DB engine is MySQL 5.7

UPD: I started with query like this:

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.project_desc,
  b.value
FROM
  projects AS a
  LEFT JOIN custom_values AS b ON a.id = b.customized_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields AS c ON b.custom_field_id = c.id
```

It surely works, but it gives 3 different strings per project with different custom_value:

[image]

I need one string per project with all values in it (see above).

Comment: You wrote `I need to write a query`, but i do not see any written query ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.project_desc,
  b.value
FROM
  projects AS a
  LEFT JOIN custom_values AS b ON a.id = b.customized_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields AS c ON b.custom_field_id = c.id
```

Comment: Yes, I started with exactly the same query. But - it gives 3 DIFFERENT strings per project with different custom_value. I need ONE string per project with all values in it. I'm going to add update to the question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.name, p.project_desc,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 7 THEN cf.value END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 8 THEN cf.value END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 9 THEN cf.value END)
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN
     custom_fields cf
     ON cv.customized_id = p.id and
        cv.customized_type = 'PROJECT' and
         cv.custom_field_id = cf.id
GROUP BY p.name, p.project_desc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like that's what I want, except I got an error:  `Error 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'bitnami_redmine.p.name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @Vladimir . . . The columns in the `SELECT` match the `GROUP BY` in this answer.

Comment: Thanks again! It works. I just accidentally confused real fields names first. Some people say that it can't be done without PIVOT, but your solution is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to Gordon Linoff, I found the solution:

```
SELECT p.name, p.description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 4 THEN cv.value END) AS value_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 5 THEN cv.value END) AS value_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cv.custom_field_id = 6 THEN cv.value END) AS value_3
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN
     custom_values cv
     ON cv.customized_id = p.id
     GROUP BY p.name, p.description;
```